# SSIS data conversion failed while impoprting CSV file into SQL table throug SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am just importing CSV file through SSIS into SQL server, I am getting the below error during the package execution.. I have used data conversion transformation for this column as Unicode string DT_WSTR in SSIS and nvarchar(255) is used in SQL server. Could you please help me on this issue

> [Flat File Source [1]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column ""MAJOR_DESCRIPTION"" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>
> [Flat File Source [1]] Error: The "output column ""MAJOR_DESCRIPTION"" (58)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column ""MAJOR_DESCRIPTION"" (58)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

Comment: In the flat file data source do any of the rows for "MAJOR_DESCRIPTION" exceed 255 chars?

Comment: The error comes from the source component, not the conversion to Unicode. Did you use the wrong field delimiter perhaps? Or actually try to read using the wrong codepage? Are you able to preview the file?

Comment: What is the file's encoding/codepage? Did you try reading a UTF8 file as ANSI or vice versa? UTF8 looks identical to ANSI for latin characters.

Comment: Maximum length is 10 in this "Major_Descrition"  from CSV file.. is there any junk data exists on this column ?

Comment: @GnanaSundaramC a CSV field isn't defined by it's *length*, it's everything between two field delimiters. Does the *file* have more than 10 characters in that field? Can you *preview* the file? Did you check which line causes the problem?

Comment: @Panagiotis, When I see preview nothing has come, all columns coming as blank and this column does not have exceed 10 characters..

Comment: and I am using for each loop container for multiple csv file pick..

Comment: @GnanaSundaramC which means you used the wrong settings in the Flat File Source. Most likely, you are using the wrong codepage. Find and use the correct ones.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis !! i removed flat file connection manager and recreated it, and when i checked preview , in that columns has blank along with value..will work on this, Thanks for your inputs !!